# Problemas com entrada de arrays em C

Tags: c, array-multidimensional

Pretendo fazer um simulador de memoria ram em C e preciso manipular strings, de inicio gostaria de usar um array 4x4 para entrada de 4 posições de memoria com 4 bits:
1010
1000
1011
0000
Algo assim.

```
#include<Stdio.h>
void main(){
char array[4][5];
printf("Informe as 4 posicoes:\n");
int i;
//leitura
for(i=0;i<4;i++){       
    scanf("%s", array[i]);
}
//impressão
printf("Imprimindo!\n");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
}
```

}

Porém a a impressão desse array vai sair meio confusa.
se eu mudar de array[4][4] para array[4][5] a impresão será normal.

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: a impressao do array sai confusa, alog do tipo:
1111000033334444
000033334444
33334444

Comment: sendo que a entrada foi 1111 0000 3333 4444

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir: http://ideone.com/gaHTtB

Answer (score 0):

Como você está trabalhando com strings, precisa criar arrays com espaço suficiente para armazenar o delimitador '\0' (contrabarra zero).

https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Strings